# Eclipse php indendation after copy/paste

Tags: php, eclipse

I recently put my eclipse up to date after a few months.
Now, when I copy then I paste code, the indentation is distorted.

Exemple :
i write this :

```
public function test()
{
    if (TRUE)
        continue;
    if (FALSE)
        continue;
    return TRUE;
}
```

i use CTRL+SHIFT+F (format) and there are no changes.
But, if I copy and then paste it gives :

```
public function test()
{
    if (TRUE)
        continue;
        if (FALSE)
            continue;
            return TRUE;
}
```

it does this only when there are no braces.
I tried to search into the formatter, but I did not find anything on that. (Properties > PHP > Code Style > Formatter)

If you could help me, I'd be happy !
Thanks

Comment: I f you look in preferences->php->editor->typing there is 'Adjust Indentation' when pasting.  It can be a bit annoying as it seems to do some 'unwanted' indentation when you add stuff to a line.

Comment: It works !!! Thanks =)

Comment: Just added as an answer for completion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option is in Preferences > PHP > Editor > Typing as 'Adjust Indentation' when pasting.

[image]